# Multiple table query with wrong rows

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

I want to get a query from two tables but the resulting query has more rows than it should be.

My statement is:

```
 SELECT *  FROM deal D, item I  WHERE D.dealstate = 'ACCEPTED' AND 
     ((D.owner = 'UserName1') OR 
      (D.itemID = I.itemID AND I.owner = 'UserName1')) AND 
       D.deadline < NOW()
```

With this statement I want to get a user's active deals. Deal table has `owner (the requester), dealID, itemID, creationdate, dealstate, deadline, explanation` and Item table has `owner (the owner of item), itemID, itemname, description`.

The problem is that I want a query with one result. Because 'UserName1' has only 1 deal. However i get a query with 10 rows, each of items matched with the deal. I thought using "JOIN" but if the user is not the owner of item, this ITEM table won't be used. Then, what should i do?

I hope I'm clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't join correctly the two tables because `D.itemID = I.itemID` isn't always true in what you wrote. Try something like

```
SELECT * FROM deal D, item I WHERE D.dealstate = 'ACCEPTED' AND D.itemID = I.itemID AND ((D.owner = 'UserName1') OR ( I.owner = 'UserName1')) AND D.deadline < NOW();
```